# Вложенный запрос SQL

Tags: sql

Необходимо создать запрос выборки из двух таблиц из одной ID и еще пару полей, (думаю это не существенно) а из другой USERNAME соответствующий ID из первой таблицы..

Я так понимаю это вложенный запрос будет, но с ними я пока только разбираюсь. подскажите . буду благодарен.

Comment: @Broouzer King, создайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com и поясните какой результат вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обязательно подзапрос. Это скорее соединение таблиц - `JOIN`.

Допустим у нас есть 2 таблицы - `Groups (id, group_name)` группы людей и `People (id, group, name)` - некие сущности, люди.

Как задача нужно выбрать всех людей состоящих в конкретной группе, допустим той которая имеет идентификатор = 1.

Для этого объеденим 2 таблицы следующим образом:

```
SELECT g.name, p.name
FROM Groups g
JOIN People p ON (g.id = p.group)
```

Ключевые вещи тут

1) `JOIN` - привязывет к одной таблице вторую (в данном случае к Groups привязываем People)

2) `ON` - условие привязывания (у нас у людей указан id группы это и будет логическим ключем для связывания)

Comment: чтоб выбрать людей из группы с идентификатором 1, join не нужен.

    select * from people where group = 1

а вы выбрали всех людей с названием групп, в которых они находятся.

Comment: да спасибо,я вот тоже до этого дошел) но всеравно еще раз сапсибо

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ну я утрировал, допустим не по ID а по имени группы

Comment: @ICE, я вас прекрасно понял, это была поправка к ответу. вы пишите "если" одно, а "следующим образом" отвечаете на другое. это не упрощение, а опечатка/ошибка - на ваш вкус. поправьте, это не сложно же, другим (не только ТС) ваш ответ тоже может быть поможет, повысьте его качество.